# Kotlin if else and let issue, can't add a command

Tags: kotlin

Maybe I'm too tired, but when adding the following Log.d in the code (now commented out) the , Studio shows a compile error on the last "else if" (where (formId == 98))... Please advise

```
formViewModel?.questionGeneralData?.id?.let { formId ->
    if (formId == 10 && !interactor.getIsRetroactive()) {
         interactor.setCaffeineCounter(answer.toString())
//       Log.d("5732", "455ryhrdhgbfhbdrfhbg")
    } else if (formId == 14) {
         if (answer == 0) {
             if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == BOOST_FLAVOR) {
                 interactor.addSkippedForm(15, FormEnums.FormType.MORNING_FORM)
             } else {
                 interactor.addSkippedForm(15, FormEnums.FormType.MORNING_FORM_REFRESH)
             }
         } else {
             interactor.removeSkippedForm(15)
         }
    } else if (formId == 97 && !interactor.getIsRetroactive()) {
         HomeSharedPrefs.put(SleepApp.getInstance().applicationContext, caffeineTaken, answer)
    } else if (formId == 98 && !interactor.getIsRetroactive()) {
         HomeSharedPrefs.put(SleepApp.getInstance().applicationContext, alcoholTaken, answer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: @Akiva adding a comment with the link to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help is helpful, replacing a post with instructions on how to format a post is not.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post

Answer (score 1):

I would say that when you do that, the return type of that first `if` statement is different than all the other statements. Since the `let` function (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) expects a type for the return value that might be causing this compilation issue.

Comment: Thanks, you showed me the direction to understand this

Comment: That would just cause it to be evaluated to type Any I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.also` instead OR return same data-type from all if-else branches.

Also, put that log statement above `interactor.setCaffeineCounter(answer.toString())`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Joao Dias answer, the solution is to switch places the Log.d with the line before it (put it after the Log.d), so first the Log is executed, and then the line after it runs, and returns the value, that the let expects